# Default parameter type checking against generic type parameter in typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

```
const defaultArg = (arg: {}) => ({})

type Arg<T> = (arg: T) => T;
type Default = Arg<{}>;

interface Test {
  (): void;
  <T>(arg: Arg<T>): void;
}

const test: Test = <T>(arg: Arg<T> = defaultArg) => { 
  //do something
}
```

TSError:

```
Type '(arg: {}) => {}' is not assignable to type 'Arg<T>'. Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'T'. '{}' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint '{}'.
```

I want to decide generic parameter passed to type `Arg` based on value of `arg`. If `arg` is undefined, I want to pass `{}` as generic parameter in type `Arg` instead of `T`.

Comment: Do any of [these](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play//#code/MYewdgzgLgBAJgUwGYEMCuAbKBBATgcxgF4YAKFAgLhgG8BfASmID4z6GBYAKCgE8AHBDDz4APABVWJclRjimRVuIDc3PoJgARZOizFhBUfWaqu3AJZgoCXKmBDxCaLW4w3ZBtQBuIc3FPuMBLMMvjUIsGeMD5+pnTcoJCw1tDUjs4kwaHhhpIwAD5aOpiwJIioJSIKrDRuAPQAVPAgMADuABYoUAD8MA11MPFcic4pUABMaU6lZBRhBmIoYLxS8MVYVSy0MI3NbZ09fQNDI8nTAMxTGUHi+sakAPpz3TliktXbpzBz+k8EBYVyrocARlDsmnAWh0ur1+oNuNwgA) meet your use case? I don't understand what you're doing, though: inside the implementation of `test` the actual `arg` is almost useless since you don't have a value of type `T` on which to call it.